# How can I get the target ids for use in the ModeArray and PathArray structures when calling SetDisplayConfig?

Tags: windows, settings, display

I want to be able to change display configurations programmatically rather than use Windows Display Setup. I can get all the information about the current setup with QueryDisplayConfig, save the values, make changes to the display settings and then restore the configuration again with SetDisplayConfig using the saved values. So this gives me a mechanism that should work as long as I can set the parameters correctly.

The issue is with the ids used in the ModeArray and PathArray structures. QueryDisplayConfig only gives information about the paths and adapters in use and for example with a three display system switching from 2 monitors cloned to all 3 monitors extended brings in adapter ids that are not available. I can retrieve all the adapterid LUID parameters for the system using IDXGIAdapter::GetDesc but it is the id parameter in the ModeArray structure that is the problem particularly when DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET is set. The source mode ids seem to be just 0, 1 etc. The target ids are not volatile like the adapter ids and do not depend on the monitor attached to the display ports. I imagine they are generated by the display driver. Trawling the registry does not yield anything obvious. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ids can be obtained by enumerating the monitor interfaces

```
BOOL GetMonitorDeviceInfo()
{
HDEVINFO                         hDevInfo;
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA         DevIntfData;
PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA DevIntfDetailData;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA                  DevData;

DWORD dwSize, dwType, dwMemberIdx;
HKEY hKey;
BYTE lpData[1024];
int i = 0;

hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
    &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR, NULL, 0, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);

if (hDevInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DevIntfData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    dwMemberIdx = 0;

    SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR,
        dwMemberIdx, &DevIntfData);

    while(GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        DevData.cbSize = sizeof(DevData);

        SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
              hDevInfo, &DevIntfData, NULL, 0, &dwSize, NULL);

        DevIntfDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize);
        DevIntfDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

        if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &DevIntfData,
            DevIntfDetailData, dwSize, &dwSize, &DevData))
        {
            // use data
        }

        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, DevIntfDetailData);

        SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
            hDevInfo, NULL, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR, ++dwMemberIdx, &DevIntfData);
    }

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
}
return 0;
}
```

The device ids are found in the uid part of the DevicePath member of the DevIntfData structure. 
E.g. DevicePath 0x0211d3dc "\?\display#dela00b#7&1e7b3638&0&uid256#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}"